# App Bar doesn't change based on Fragment in navigation component

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-jetpack, android-appbarlayout, android-jetpack-navigation

In my app i am using navigation component.i have used only one Activity and couple of Fragment.MainActivity hosts all the Fragment. i have set custom AppBar in MainActivity.i want to change the AppBar for a certain Fragment.to do so here is my code

```
public class MessageFragment extends Fragment {
private FragmentMessageBinding messageBinding;
private ChatActionBarBinding barBinding;
ActionBar actionBar;

public MessageFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    messageBinding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, R.layout.fragment_message, container, false);
    return messageBinding.getRoot();

}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    actionBar = ((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
    actionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
    actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity());
    barBinding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(layoutInflater, R.layout.chat_action_bar, null, false);
    actionBar.setCustomView(barBinding.getRoot());

}
}
```

when i navigate to that perticular Fragment The AppBar changes as expected .But the problem is when i press the back button or navigate to another fragment the AppBar remains same.it doesn't change based on the fragment.
Here is some Screenshot of my app.

is there any solution?

[image: this is the particular fragment]

[image: The App bar shows here comes from previous fragment.when user press the back button]

[image: should look like this]